# Linear Factorization of $X^n+1$ in $\mathbb{F}p$

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, prime-numbers

I was just playing around with SageMath and noticed that I can find for each $n < 200$ (at least) a prime $p$ such that the polynomial $X^n+1$ factorizes into polynomials of degree one in $\mathbb{F}_p[X]$. I have a feeling that this statement is in general true, but is there an easy way to see this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are essentially asking that the field contain the $(2n)^{th}$ roots of unity.  In order for that to happen we need a prime $p$ such that $2n\,|\,(p-1)$.  Equivalently, we want a prime $p\equiv 1 \pmod {2n}$.  Since $\gcd(1, 2n)=1$, Dirichlet assures us that infinitely many such primes exist.

Example:  $n=17$.  We want $p$ such that $p\equiv 1 \pmod {34}$.  The least such is $p=103$ and we get $$x^{17}+1\equiv (x + 1) (x + 8) (x + 9) (x + 13) (x + 14) (x + 23) (x + 30) (x + 34) (x + 61)\cdots  $$ $$\cdots (x + 64) (x + 66) (x + 72) (x + 76) (x + 79) (x + 81) (x + 93) (x + 100) \pmod {103}$$

Comment: Perfect. Thank you! :)